# php function to return sql results that contain arrays, as an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

So im having a problem (obviously). I have the following MySQL table data

```
7   USER1       1,1,1,10,1      The Guys Team   8,7,13,14,16
8    USER1      1,1,1,10,1  The Girls Team  7,12,15
10  USER1       1,1,1,10,1  Dog Team    8,7,14,15
```

I wrote a function to retrieve the data, and return it.

```
function ShowSetTeams($coach){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `teams` WHERE coach = '$coach'") or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
        foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
            $id = $row['id'];
            $teamname = $row['teamname'];
            $team = $row['team'];
            $event = $row['event'];
            $push .= array($id, $teamname, $team, $event);
    }
    return $push;
}
```

When i call the function, as below

```
$info = ShowSetTeams("USER1");
```

I get this

```
ArrayArrayArray
```

I tried echoing $info[0], $info[1], and $info[2], but get this

```
Arr
```

So each line in the info array, is the result array. I should be able to do $info[0][0] and get the first ID value, from the first result right?

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array
```

Im at a loss. **How can i get to each of the values of the returned arrays?** And more to the point, *how could i run a foreach operation on them* such as

```
foreach( $info as $key => $value){
$key[0] //ID
$key[1] //TEAMNAME
$key[2] //TEAM
$key[3] //EVENT
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using string concatenation instead of array notation:

```
$push[] = array($id, $teamname, $team, $event);
```

You should also initialise `$push = array();` before you start using it.

You're also doing a lot of extra work... you could just do:

```
function ShowSetTeams($coach)
{   
    $push = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, teamname, team, event FROM `teams` WHERE coach = '$coach'") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        // I doubt you actually need to run stripslashes on your data...
        $row = array_map('stripslashes', $row);
        $push[] = $row;
    }

    return $push;
}
```

Unless you have to, I wouldn't use re-key it to a numerically indexed array either - you're just making it harder to understand in your later code. Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) to do this

Comment: I will explore this further later on, but thanks for the advice. Too late to switch it all now though.

Comment: hi greg, why do you use the array_values? wouldn't that de-assoc the array? it seems he wants the info as an associative array. so why not just `$push[] = $row`?

Comment: @tharkun I used array_values because that is what @Patrick's code does

Comment: @Greg: But with `mysql_fetch_array` you will have all values twice.

Comment: I thought he was using assoc... guess I'm so used to it I just read it everywhere heh. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Don't concatenate the $push but use

```
$push[] = array();

return $push;
```

A few other remarks:

- your database schema is not properly normalised! you should not have strings of userIDs stored in your table but have a reference many-to-many table between the teams table and the players table.
- you should never (almost never) use the `*` selector in queries. You build yourself traps with that. Instead indicate the exact columns you want to retrieve.
- you could get the same information without having to put together the $push array yourself. If the database columns are properly named you can use a fetch_assoc and just do `$push[] = $row`

Answer (score 1):

I think they problem is with the line:

```
 $push .= array($id, $teamname, $team, $event);
```

That treats $push as a string and concatenates an array which gets turned into a string. Try:

```
 $push[] = array($id, $teamname, $team, $event);
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re using a [string concatenation and assignment operator `.=`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) that will convert your arrays into strings. Try the array push operator `$array[]` instead:

```
function ShowSetTeams($coach) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `teams` WHERE coach = '$coach'") or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = array(stripslashes($row['id'], stripslashes($row['teamname'], stripslashes($row['team']), stripslashes($row['event']));
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`
2. You should define $push as array by `$push = array();` before "while"
3. You should `use $push[] = ...` instead of `$push .= ...`